# Divergence theorem for the set of singular positive semidefinite matrices.

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, positive-semidefinite, divergence-theorem

Let us consider the space of symmetric positive-definite (SPD) $\mathscr{P}^d$ matrices of dimensions $d \times d$. It is well known that this space is a pointed convex cone, which represents a differentiable manifold of finite dimension.

The boundary of such a space, denoted by $\partial \mathscr{P}^d$ is the set of singular positive-semidefinite matrices.

Due to Alexandrov theorem (a convex function $f$ is $C^2$ almost everywhere), I believe (but I am not sure) that the divergence theorem can be applied in such a space. But, again, I am not sure and I struggle to find reference on any application of divergence theorem in such space, clearly the problem is the boundary.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: The space $\mathscr{P}^d$ with its closure is a semialgebraic set. A semialgebraic set can be written as a finite union of smooth manifolds, $\mathscr{R}_r$, where $r=0, 1, ..., n$ represents the rank of the matrix. Then it is clear that $\partial \mathscr{P}^d= \cup_{r=0}^{n-1} \mathscr{R}_r$ and divergence theorem applies for piecewise smooth manifolds. This should be correct.

Comment: yup cones are pretty ‘mild’, but this is a non-compact cone, so you should impose suitable growth restrictions on your function. Anyway, Lang has some concluding remarks about Stokes’ theorem with singularities in his real and functional analysis text, so you might want to check there for some general remarks.